# how to mute video ads? firebase admob react native

Tags: react-native, firebase-admob, video-ads

I have ads module firebase-admob. I want disable volume when video-ads will showing. now

```
const interstitial = InterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(adUnitId, {
requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,});
interstitial.load();
interstitial.show();
```

config here:

```
    admob()
        .setRequestConfiguration({
            // Update all future requests suitable for parental guidance
            maxAdContentRating: MaxAdContentRating.G,
            
          
            

            // Indicates that you want your content treated as child-directed for purposes of COPPA.
            tagForChildDirectedTreatment: true,

            // Indicates that you want the ad request to be handled in a
            // manner suitable for users under the age of consent.
            tagForUnderAgeOfConsent: true,
        })
        .then(() => {
        });
```

I want mute video-ads by default. If its possible, how I can do this?

Comment: The only way (I found) is to disable video-content for interstitial-ads